# Output line break into Jade-generated HTML from inside JS Variable

Tags: javascript, html, pug

This is my Jade file

```
 - var itens = ["Sem limites de<br/>vendas", "Sem limites de visitas", "Sem limites de e-mails", "Sem cooparticipação"];
[...]
each item, i in itens
    div.col-xs-12.col-md-6
        div.col-xs-5.np.l
            img(src="img/#{imgs[i]}", title="#{item}", aria-label="#{item}", alt="#{item}").col-xs-12
        div.col-xs-7.np.r
            h3 #{item}
            p #{itens2[i]}
```

And this is what gets outputted:

[image]

What's the best alternative to output a real html line-break inside this h3 tag?

Thanks in advance. o/

Comment: Never worked with Jade before, but try `\n` instead of `<br/>` in the String variables.

Comment: try this `"Sem limites de"<br>"vendas"`

Comment: It still won't work, because `<br>||<br/>` is stored as string.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter `\n` created a new line in a string, but for a line break work as a line break inside a HTML tag, `<br>` as HTML. But jade inserts it as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jade is escaping anything inside #{} attributes.  Use !{} or !=.  However, I don't think you should be putting HTML tags inside attributes.

```
- var itens = ["Sem limites de<br/>vendas", "Sem limites de visitas", "Sem limites de e-mails", "Sem cooparticipação"];
[...]
each item, i in itens
    div.col-xs-12.col-md-6
        div.col-xs-5.np.l
            img(src="img/#{imgs[i]}", title="#{item}", aria-label="#{item}", alt="#{item}").col-xs-12
        div.col-xs-7.np.r
            h3!= item
            p= itens2[i]
```

Comment: Yeah, I shouldn't. I misused my variable to exemplify... But your answer did solve my situation. Thank you a lot!

Comment: "However, I don't think you should be putting HTML tags inside attributes" ... in this case, what's the alternative?

Comment: [Tag interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) ... var itens = ["Sem limites de#[br]vendas", ... for one, but my preference would be not to have any direct formatting the page content.  I would think an HTML spacing entity would be better in this case, too.

Answer (score 2):

(I don't think this is required, but jade is picky about syntax) Change:

```
["Sem limites de<br/>vendas"...
```

Into:

```
["Sem limites de <br /> vendas"...
```

(You'll definitely want to do this) And then change:

```
h3 #{item}
p #{itens2[i]}
```

Into:

```
h3
    | #{item}
p
    | #{itens2[i]}
```

And you should be good to go. I ran into a similar issue when I was building a content management system in node when outputting local variables. Adding the pipe into the array allows the local to float on a new line and be rendered correctly.

You may need to pipe other locals that are going to contain any special characters or HTML elements as well.

I was able to replicate this and output the line break fairly easily.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Have you tried to put the pipe into the array index? ["| Sem limites de <br /> vendas...